# How can I remove specific elements from a body of text?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm digging into back-end development (as a UI designer) and wanted to practice what I've learned by using cheerio, request, and express to scrape an astrology website for a paragraph of text. From this site, I pull the selected data to my server and pass it onto the client - which succeeded. The problem I've come against is that on the astrology site, the Date and the Astrology Reading are in the same paragraph tag and I can't separate them. It comes out looking like this:

*Jun 7, 2019: Today is a great day to experience new things—they should be both as pedestrian as a new breakfast cereal [...]*

I originally considered using the replace method, but have been moving towards the substring method instead. My thoughts were that I could set the starting value to 12, in which case that would account for the minimum of characters in the date. I could then replace any spaces that occur before the first character of the reading (in this case, 'Today'). The problem is that if there are 2 digits for the current day, I risk removing the first character from the reading.

Is this the logic I have to play around with or is there a simpler method that I could use?

Comment: I'm not sure I exactly understand the output you want, but why don't you find the colon ':'?

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply split values by first `:`

```js
let str = `Jun 7, 2019: Today is a great day to experience new things—they should be both as pedestrian as a new breakfast cereal [...]`
let str2 = `Jun 17, 2019: Today is a great day to experience new things—they should be both as pedestrian as a new breakfast cereal [...]`

let dateAndInfo = (str) =>{
  return str.split(/(^[^:]+):/).filter(Boolean).map(e=>e.trim())
}

console.log(dateAndInfo(str))
console.log(dateAndInfo(str2))
```

Comment: I used your method, but formulated it a bit differently. What I had was let elements = content.split(':'); and created a date and reading variable from elements[0] and elements[1]. Thank you for your suggestion, it let me in the right direction!

Comment: I left out a bit but the content variable is the entire paragraph that I mentioned in the post (Jun 7, 2019: Today is a great day [...] etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the substr method in conjunction with the indexOf method that will find the index of the first ":" character. Start at the location of the ":" and extract the rest of the string.

```
finalStr = str2.substr(str2.indexOf(":") + 1)
//returns everything after the ":" at the end of the date string.
```